# Launching an instance from Marketplace will work on regular Reserved Instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have bought a reserved instance from AWS directly and not from the marketplace, then I have an instance launched from the Quick Start that uses Amazon Linux AMI. Then currently I installed cPanel in it but I found out that the version of Linux AMI that I am using is not supported by cPanel. cPanel told me that I should use a lower version of Amazon Linux AMI that is supported by cPanel, they sent me a link that goes to marketplace with their supported version of Linux AMI.

Before I proceed, I just need to confirm that by launching the same specs that I used on my Reserved Instance will also work if I launched an instance from the marketplace?

Does any have an idea regarding this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you own a reserved instance, if you launch an instance of the right class in the right AZ it uses your RI automatically. The AMI or marketplace is irrelevant, and I found your description of what you've done there rather confusing.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation is confusing. You are right, if I lauch an instance with same specs as my RI the it will use it automatically. I did the same when I purchase instance on marketplace, so does it mean I'm on the right track?

Comment: @kagat-kagat yes, because a reserved instance is not a literal, actual instance. If you reserve one instance, then launch two matching instances, then terminate one of them, the remaining instance is automatically considered to be the reserved instance, no matter which one of the two it is... because reserved instance pricing is applied after-the-fact, by the billing department.

Comment: "*in the right AZ"* @Tim note that reserved instances now also offer a [region-wide option](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-reserved-instance-update-convertible-ris-and-regional-benefit/) that is not tied to a specific AZ.  This option, if selected, provides the same discount, but not an actual capacity reservation (which is the second, and presumably less often discussed/needed capability, of reserved instances).